# Apply for role - no activation email after account approval

Tags: users

After admin users select 'Approve' for a role application, the account automatically becomes active, but it bypasses the notification to the user that their account is active and critically, they don't get the One time login URL where they can set their password.

Is there any way to provide this token in an action of the Apply for role approval trigger?

Comment: Is your website sending any mails at all? To check, you might try to get a password recovery mail for the admain user.

Comment: Yes it's sending all other emails without bother, eg the registration email is sent to the user.